# Gravity keyframe not working on render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation, keyframes

I'm doing a 10 second animation for a project at uni. Part of this animation consists of a box falling on a button to activate it. I wanted this to start at frame 190 and as nothing else uses gravity in the animation I decided to keyframe the scene gravity so there isn't gravity up until frame 190. This worked great and on viewport mode I can see the animation working, however when rendering the image the box won't fall.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You have to bake the animation before rendering.Have you baked the animation?

Comment: Just did that and is working like a charm! I feel really stupid, thank you for your help :)